# How do I make the quantity dropdown work right in cart page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Since I don't know how to disable the quantity hover. I'm going to use the dropdown quantity. I have the code but the quantity dropdown doesn't update the right number in the cart page. Do you know why? For example if I my quantity is 3, it will say 1 in my cart page.
Also when I choose my quantity 3, and then I click the "add to cart button" , it will say "Please choose product options" because I didn't choose a size. The quantity start from 1 again, it doesn't stay the same what I chose before.
Also this have to work in mobile too. Can you help me with that? Thanks

```
// override the quantity input with a dropdown
function woocommerce_quantity_input() {
global $product;
global $post;
global $prod_quant_default;



$prod_quant_default = 1;     // <----------- Default Amount
$category_ID = '26';         // <----------- Case Category

$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $product_cat_id = $term->term_id;
    break;
}


// Sets QTY for Cases (Cat 26)          
if ($product_cat_id == $category_ID){
    $prod_quant_default = 1;
            //break;
  }


$defaults = array(
    'input_name'    => 'quantity',
    'input_value'   => '1',
    'max_value'     => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', '', $product ),
    'min_value'     => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', '', $product ),
    'step'      => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_step', '1', $product ),
    'style'     => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_style', 'float:left; margin-right:10px;', $product )
);
if ( ! empty( $defaults['min_value'] ) )
    $min = $defaults['min_value'];
else $min = 1;

if ( ! empty( $defaults['max_value'] ) )
    $max = $defaults['max_value'];
else $max = 10;

if ( ! empty( $defaults['step'] ) )
    $step = $defaults['step'];
else $step = 1;


$options = '';
for ( $count = $min; $count <= $max; $count = $count+$step ) {
    global $prod_quant_default;
            if ($count == $prod_quant_default) {
                $selected = ' selected="selected" ';
                }
            else {
                $selected = null;
            }


            $options .= '<option' . $selected . ' value="' . $count . '">' . $count . '</option>';

}
echo '<div class="quantity_select" style="' . $defaults['style'] . '"><select name="' . esc_attr( $defaults['input_name'] ) . '" title="' . _x( 'Qty', 'Product quantity input tooltip', 'woocommerce' ) . '" class="qty">' . $options . '</select></div>';
```

}

Comment: What are you trying to do that you modified the quantity inputs in the first place? What is a quantity hover? That's not part of WooCommerce default that I'm aware of.

Comment: No, ignore the quantity hover. I mean i don't know how disable the quantity hover. I will convert quantity to dropdown.

Comment: But when I convert the quantity to dropdown. I have some problem in cart page and product page. can you help me with that? @helgatheviking

Comment: Why are you changing the input type in the first place? What's the advantage over the standard input?

Comment: Because I want match my size dropdown. @helgatheviking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to override the `quantity-input.php` template that is called by the `woocommerce_quantity_input()` function.

Your theme's new `woocommerce/global/quantity-input.php` template override:

```
<?php
/**
 * Product quantity inputs
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/global/quantity-input.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you (the theme developer).
 * will need to copy the new files to your theme to maintain compatibility. We try to do this.
 * as little as possible, but it does happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will.
 * be bumped and the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.5.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}
?>
<div class="quantity">
    <?php
    $options = '';
    for ( $count = $args['min_value']; $count <= $args['max_value']; $count = $count+$args['step'] ) {
        $options .= '<option' . selected( $args['input_value'], $count, false ) . ' value="' . $count . '">' . $count . '</option>';
    } 
    if ( $options ){ ?>
    <select name="<?php echo esc_attr( $args['input_name'] ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Qty', 'Product quantity input tooltip', 'woocommerce' ) ?>" class="qty" /><?php echo $options;?></select>
    <?php } else {
        printf( '%s <input type="hidden" name="%s" value="%s" />', $args['input_value'], $args['input_name'], $args['input_value'] );
    } ?>
</div>
```

Note: All my local testing is on bleeding-edge WooCommerce, I'm not sure if the 2.5 version listed here will work with current WC2.4.X.  But the idea would be similar.

If you need to modify the min/max defaults, you can do so via filter in your theme's `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', 'so_input_max', 20, 2 );
function so_input_max( $max, $product ){
    return 10;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', 'so_input_min', 20, 2 );
function so_input_min( $min, $product ){
    return 1;
}
```

Remember, these are just the defaults in the case where no min/max are directly specified when calling the `woocommerce_quantity_input()` function.

### EDIT

I improved the template above to have the right input names/values ( `<select>` definitely had the wrong name attribute) and to show a hidden quantity input in the case where there are no options (this is what Woo does when a product is sold individually so that so that the quantity is not lost when updating the cart).

There are no options on the cart page because the `cart.php` template doesn't set a max if the item's stock isn't managed, or if backorders are allowed. A null max kills the `for` loop in our template. With the min at 0 and the max at null, there's nothing to loop through and no `<option>` tags are created.

To fix that we can filter the `woocommerce_cart_item_quantity` in the `cart.php` template. This would also need to be added to your `functions.php`.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', 'so_cart_item_quantity', 10, 3 );
function so_cart_item_quantity( $product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item ){
    $_product = $cart_item['data'];
     if ( ! $_product->is_sold_individually() ) {
        $max_value = $_product->backorders_allowed() ? '' : $_product->get_stock_quantity();
        // set a max of 10 as default if max is null
        $max_value = $max_value != '' ? $max_value : 10;
        $product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
                'input_name'  => "cart[{$cart_item_key}][qty]",
                'input_value' => $cart_item['quantity'],
                'max_value'   => $max_value,
                'min_value'   => '0'
        ), $_product, false );
    }
    return $product_quantity;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but the quantity it's not showing in the cart page, but the total is right. For example , 3 X $12 = $36 , the 3 is not showing up, The quantity is not showing up. I can't even select the number in cart page. In the product page when I choose the quantity 3, and then I click the "add to cart button" , it will say "Please choose product options" because I didn't choose a size. The quantity start from 1 again, it doesn't stay the same what I chose before. I want it to stay the same number. Thanks for your help. Appreciated. Does it work correct for you?

Comment: I thought it worked for me, but I move through these questions kind of fast sometimes. I've made some corrections and it works for me now. You can see a [temporary example](https://wordpress-helgatheviking.c9.io/product/woo-album-1/)

Comment: Thank you it works the quantity number is right in my cart  but I don't have a quantity dropdown on my cart. Can you take a look at my code? did I make a mistake in my cart quantity? I put the code jsfiddle because it doesn't let paste the code in comment field/
https://jsfiddle.net/959b6ux2/

Comment: No one can read code in comments anyway. Pastebin is also a good site. I'm not sure what file that's supposed to be in, but it includes the errors I described in my edit. Have you tried it as I've written (since my edit)? You can see that it is working in the link I posted in my last comment.

Comment: Yes, your link was working great. that is what I want. For me, everything works fine except the cart quantity dropdown. The quantity number is correct, but my cart quantity doesn't jave the dropdown, so I can't change the number.

Comment: Are you filtering `woocommerce_cart_item_quantity` like shown above? because you should (in theory) be getting a max value now. can you also `var_dump($args);` somewhere in the overridden `quantity-input.php` template.

Comment: The code works :) I forgot to include the other part. Thanks . Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue where on cart update using Woo 2.6 with AJAX, the select breaks.  If you remove the trailing / here:

```
...', 'woocommerce' ) ?>" class="qty" />
```

To:

```
', 'woocommerce' ) ?>" class="qty">
```

It will now work.